# Easy way to replace images in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a TYPO3 installation where I want to replace roughly around 200 images. The original images have not been optimized for the web well and some have unfitting extensions (like PNG for an image that should clearly be JPG).

Other than going into each individual page and replacing the images, is there an easy and fast way to replace all those images?

It TYPO3 8.7.25

Comment: normaly images are refactored by TYPO3 before they are delivered as part of a web page. especially if the original image is bigger than the image is visible in the page. each refactoring is connected with an optimization - as far as the configuration is done well. ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick is necessary to be installed on the server. you can test these features in the install-tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the file list module and just replace the images? FAL *(File Abstraction Layer)* should handle the file relations in all content elements.

Comment: the alternative would be, I guess, rebuild the relations between the images and the content via the tables `sys_file` and `sys_file_reference`

Comment: While this IS a nice way to do this, I don't seem to get the processed images to rerender for some reason. Even though I deleted the whole cache and also the "processed" folder.

Comment: There is an option for it in the install tool. Its under Maintenance -> Remove Temporary Assets.